# distribution of data vs density estimation

Tags: density-function

I think this is a very basic question but I'm confused and need clarification please help me

density estimation vs distribution of data what is the difference and Is Kernel density estimation learns the distribution of data ???

Comment: The density estimation is to estimate the probability distribution of data.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really make sense to ask about density estimation *vs.* the distribution of data. It's the equivalent of asking about weight vs. scale, or width vs. ruler.

The distribution of the data is like weight or width: It's a characteristic. Density estimation is like scale or ruler: It's a way of assessing the characteristic. And, just as there are different kinds of scales, there are different ways to assess the distribution.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying I got it sorry for that simple question